# gcp.bigquery reference page not available any more?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datalab

I have been using gcp.bigquery python module in datalab for a long time, and the reference page is very helpful. It contains all the attributes and methods for BigQuery jobs, datasets, tables, clients, and so on.

http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/datalab/_modules/gcp/bigquery.html

However, the page is not available any more, which gives me a 404 error. I have been searching online for a similar one, however, I didn't get any.

Does anyone know what happened? Did they move the page to somewhere else? Or if you have a better reference page.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "datalab" repository was migrated from the "GoogleCloudPlatform" GitHub organization to the ["googledatalab"](https://github.com/googledatalab) one.

The up-to-date link is http://googledatalab.github.io/datalab/_modules/gcp/bigquery.html

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about that specific page, but [the API reference in BigQuery's public documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/) sounds like it should serve a similar purpose.

Comment: Thank you, Danny.  this page is more reference for API, but for gcp.bigquery.  The page I provided contains every method and attribute for the python module. It is very useful and detailed. If you search <gcp.bigquery> using google, the first two results will be the link I talked about, but they are not available any more.